# Intelij not resolving symbols

Tags: intellij-idea

Intelji ultimate edition after update 2021.1 keeps not resolving symbols each time I open it.

but the problem is being fixed after invalidating caches each time I open it on ubuntu 20.04 with build number u-211-6693-111

the problem is really annoying because it takes a long time to re open the intelij

Comment: Any exceptions in the log? (Help | Show Log in ...)

Comment: Try fixed builds from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391